# Is AWS Data Pipeline scalable exporting DynamoDB Table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

Here are the following things I did,

Increased read units to 10000 for the table that need to get exported. I did wait for the capacity to get setup before creating pipeline.

In the pipeline set the ReadThroughputRatio to 75%.

[image]

Initiated the export using AWS Data Pipeline, It was fast in the beginning and then going very slow.

[image]

You can clearly see the read unit is increases and data pipeline is not using the maximum read. Maximum it used only 2500 read units.

It is only using average of 250 reads and progress is very slow.

[image]

What am I missing the process of setting up the pipeline to use the maximum read capacity?

Screenshot for Capacity:
[image]

Comment: you might need to modify the capacity units for any keys you're querying on as well. What is reading from that dynamo and how is it doing so?

Comment: It is a full export of table, not a query of any kind with any specific attributes.

Comment: ah ok, i misread. It's still probably an index, what kind of indexes do you have on the table, especially global or local secondary indexes? and what are the read units on those?

Comment: There are no indexes other than partition key and sort key. Do I need an additional index to improve the throughput?

Comment: I don't think you need an additional index, but I'm thinking that the index that you have right now might have its own RCU which is lower than the table's RCU

Comment: Do you any documentation relating to that ? And what that max value will be?

Comment: when you go into the table and click on "edit provisioned capacity" can you take a screenshot of that?

Comment: Added screenshot as mentioned.

Comment: hmm that is weird, which region is your dynamodb in?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195971/discussion-between-kannaiyan-and-naguib-ihab).